# Multiple loops on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Probably simple but cant get my head around this simple task...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE this = that";
$result = mysql_query($mycon, $query);

while ($tablerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
  do this
}
```

Can I rerun this while loop on the same $result without rerunning the query?

i.e.:

```
while ($tablerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
  do something else using the same data
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not do both things in one loop?

Comment: Yes You can use

Comment: ok I'm building a table row by row and some of the data for the next row is in the first query that was used to build the first row of the table. I'm sure this is staring my in the face but can't see it!!

Comment: The `mysql_` interface? Really? In 2017? Why? It's been deprecated for years now, and will disappear soon.

Comment: @O.Jones - please see below - the inline editor took exception to mysqli and changed it to mysql - we are all using the new stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the while loop again but after every `while` loop place this code:

```
mysql_data_seek($tablerow , 0);
```

As, this above function always resets the pointer to its starting point in loop.

Find the full code below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE this = that";
$result = mysql_query($mycon, $query);

while ($tablerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
  do this
}
mysql_data_seek($tablerow , 0);

//Do something you want

//Then again

while ($tablerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
  do this
}
mysql_data_seek($tablerow , 0);
```

For security purpose and `mysql` is deprecated also, always try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

I hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: it's not only about security! `mysql_*` has been deprecated! and should not be used any more!

Comment: @lance, i am glad it helped you.

Comment: Sorry all.. I am using mysqli but this editor took exception to it and changed it to mysql

Comment: @hassan, thanks bro, now i have addressed about mysql_ deprecation in the answer, you can see there in my updated answer.

Comment: @Lance if it helped you and you are satisfied with the answer then, please mark the answer right or vote for it, so that those who are in really need or facing the same problem can find this answer here, Thanks.

Comment: @PrateekVerma Hi Prateek.. I have hit the up button 300 times but it tells me I'm pretty low in the "reputation" stakes here so your answer doesn't get bumped up.

Comment: Hey... Prateek's answer was spot on and solved my problem perfectly. Please bump his answer up...

Comment: Please review this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hope, this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause duplicate code which is a bad practice. 
Use the same loop.